# Talend Lookup: Retrieving Client IDs Based on Client Names

Tags: join, lookup, talend, tmap

I have the following tables :

```
Sale ID,Sale Amount,Client 1,Client 2
1,500,John,Alice
2,700,Bob,Sarah
3,300,Alice,Michael
4,900,Sarah,Bob


Client Name,Client ID
John,100
Alice,101
Bob,102
Sarah,103
Michael,104
```

my goal is to map each client to its ID . but each sale has two clients . how to perform multiple lookups based on the same column

the result should be :

```
SaleId, Client1Id,Client1Id
1,100,101
2,102,103
3,101,104
```

Reading the ID file two times isn't an optimal solutions .

Answer (score 0):

Use (in a tPreJob) a tHashOutput to load the ClientName-ClientId pairs in memory. Then link it a tHashInput to do the mapping when you need it.

You may need to add these components to the Palette first.

[image]

and then

[image]